# Boto3 session get_credentials() is not returning token

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

My application needs to use AWS v4 authentication and I was able to retrieve the token earlier. Now it returns `None`:

```py
session = boto3.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials().get_frozen_credentials()
ACCESS_KEY_ID = credentials.access_key
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = credentials.secret_key
SESSION_TOKEN = credentials.token # Not working
region = session.region_name

print(f'SESSION_TOKEN: {SESSION_TOKEN}')
```

Output:

```
SESSION_TOKEN: None
```

Here are the contents of my local configuration file:

```sh
$ cat ~/.aws/credentials

[default]
aws_access_key_id = <DEFAULT_ACCESS_KEY_ID>
aws_secret_access_key = <DEFAULT_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY>
```

What is the cause and how do I retrieve the token?

Answer (score 3):

The cause is that you have no sources of credentials available.

When you call `Session.get_credentials()`, it tries to load credentials from [a series of sources](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#configuring-credentials), such as configuration files in `$HOME/.aws`, or an EC2 instance role.

When you were able to retrieve the token, you were running in an environment that supported one of those methods -- most likely an EC2 instance or Lambda function. When you're trying to do it now -- probably from your personal computer -- you don't.

The way to resolve the problem is to configure credentials in your current environment, following the link above.

When you're using credentials, be aware that not all credentials sources use a security token. You should be prepared for either case.

Comment: Added my local credentials profile to question. I noticed that it does not contain `aws_session_token ` whereas the example in the doc you link does. Should I add this, and if so how?

Comment: @abk - no, as I said in my last paragraph, not all credentials use a security token. You need to be prepared for that in your code.

Comment: Looking at your other question, you would omit the `session_token` argument from the Elasticsearch constructor if you don't have one.